# Why can't I separate the fraction inside a fraction to the outside

Tags: fractions, fractional-part

I know when I have something of this form

\begin{equation}
{a} \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{s + \frac{1}{T}}{s + \frac{1}{\alpha T}}
\end{equation}
I multiply out the fractional part,  α with the bottom to get

\begin{equation}
{a} \frac{s + \frac{1}{T}}{\alpha s + \frac{1}{T}}
\end{equation}

---

But, if I instead have

\begin{equation}
{a}  \frac{\frac{1}{\alpha} ( s + \frac{1}{T} )}{s + \frac{1}{\alpha T}}
\end{equation}

with the fractional part

\begin{equation}\frac{1}{\alpha} \end{equation} in the numerator instead.

---

I know I can't take the fractional part out of the equation in this second instance. But, I don't know why that is. I know this is a fairly basic rule, but I haven't done algebra in quite a while. So, I wanted to ask for clarification.

Comment: why do you say that? Both expressions are equal!

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. I'm not sure if I'm pointing out a typo or answering your question by saying that the first expression with $\dfrac1\alpha$ in front and the third expression with it in the numerator are equal.

Comment: I must be missing something basic about the algebra then. I didn't think I could separate out the second one the same way. Again, I'm a little rusty in the area of algebra. I'm actually trying to prove that two lead compensator equations are equivalent, which is where I ran into this expression.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can't take the fractional part out of the equation in this second instance

What?  Yes you can.  (Technically it's "expression" and not "equation.")

In general, $\dfrac{AB}C = A\dfrac BC$, as long as $C \ne 0$ since otherwise these expressions are undefined.

In your case:

$$
a \ \frac{\frac1\alpha ( s + \frac1T )}{s + \frac1{\alpha T}}
 = a \ \frac1\alpha \frac{ s + \frac1T}{s + \frac1{\alpha T}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

if you have this 
\begin{equation}
{a}  \frac{\frac{1}{\alpha} ( s + \frac{1}{T} )}{s + \frac{1}{\alpha T}}
\end{equation}

then it is exactly the same as
\begin{equation}
{a} \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{s + \frac{1}{T}}{s + \frac{1}{\alpha T}}
\end{equation}

And it is a matter of asociation: Lets call $b:= \frac{1}{\alpha},\ \ c:=s + \frac{1}{T},\ \ d:=s + \frac{1}{\alpha T}$. Then, rewriting the fractions as divisions, we have that

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\frac{1}{\alpha} ( s + \frac{1}{T} )}{s + \frac{1}{\alpha T}} = (b.c):d =b.(c:d) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{s + \frac{1}{T}}{s + \frac{1}{\alpha T}}
\end{equation}

Comment: I guess where I get confused is that I can multiply out the bottom of the fraction with the bottom, or multiply the whole fraction with the top.

Comment: But whether or not you can multiply $\alpha$ with what I called $d$ is another question ( whose answer is similar to this one). From the right hand side of the equality, you have already convinced yourself ( it is the first thing you've written above) that you can multiply $\alpha$ with $d$.

Comment: Do you See what I said? See that, in my development, I never used that $b$ is a fraction, it is valid for any real number $b$.

Comment: I see what you mean. Once I thought about it for a minute, it made sense the two are equivalent.